# Which template engine and Ajax framework/toolkit can load templates from JAR files?

Tags: ajax, templates, frameworks, toolkit

Which Template-Engine and Ajax-Framework/-Toolkit is able to load template information from JAR-Files?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean server-side template engines, you can get Velocity to load its templates from the classpath (which includes JAR files). Check out the section "Configuring the Resource Loaders (template loaders)" in the [Developer Guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html#configuring_resource_loaders).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.ztemplates.org which is simple and easy to learn. This one allows you to put all related templates, javascript and css into one jar and use it transparently. Means you even have not to care about declaring the needed javascript in your page when using a provided component, as the framework does it for you.